# Symfony forms, guess required attribute in association fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

when I'm adding fields of my entity in Symfony forms, the entity annotations are mapped and based on this Symfony guess if my field can be nullable or not, so far so good, such as this dump:

```
public 'fieldMappings' => 
array (size=5)
  'acl' => 
    array (size=9)
      'fieldName' => string 'acl' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'smallint' (length=8)
      'scale' => int 0
      'length' => null
      'unique' => boolean false
      'nullable' => boolean true
      'precision' => int 0
      'options' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      'columnName' => string 'acl' (length=3)
  'id' => 
    array (size=10)
      'fieldName' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'type' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'scale' => int 0
      'length' => null
      'unique' => boolean true
      'nullable' => boolean false
      'precision' => int 0
      'options' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      'columnName' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'id' => boolean true
```

But if I have associating fields (foreign keys), Symfony has a different mapping structure and doesn't guess if the field can be nullable or not, such as this dump:

```
public 'associationMappings' => 
array (size=3)
  'userObj' => 
    array (size=19)
      'fieldName' => string 'userObj' (length=7)
      'joinColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'cascade' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      'inversedBy' => null
      'targetEntity' => string 'AdminBundle\Entity\User' (length=23)
      'fetch' => int 2
      'type' => int 2
      'mappedBy' => null
      'isOwningSide' => boolean true
      'sourceEntity' => string 'AdminBundle\Entity\UserAcl' (length=26)
      'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
      'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
      'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
      'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
      'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
      'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'joinColumnFieldNames' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
  'storeObj' => 
    array (size=19)
      'fieldName' => string 'storeObj' (length=8)
      'joinColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'cascade' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      'inversedBy' => null
      'targetEntity' => string 'AdminBundle\Entity\Store' (length=24)
      'fetch' => int 2
      'type' => int 2
      'mappedBy' => null
      'isOwningSide' => boolean true
      'sourceEntity' => string 'AdminBundle\Entity\UserAcl' (length=26)
      'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
      'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
      'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
      'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
      'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
      'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'joinColumnFieldNames' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
```

So in these cases the required attribute needs to be configured manually, otherwise it will be true (is the default value by Symfony forms).

Anyone know how Symfony can guess the required attribute in these cases?
My entity have the following annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $userObj;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Store")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_store", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $storeObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [TypeGuesser service](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/type_guesser.html). That's a hell of a lot of work, though, so why not manually set the fields once and be done with it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for now I'm doing this, but it would be good if Symfony do this work the same way as it does with the remaining fields.